# How to spawn larvae without going back to base

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

I heard on some Day9 screencast (can't find it anymore) that you can spawn larvae with all your queens without going back to the hatcheries and actually clicking on them (the queens will spawn larvae on the closest hatchery or something like that).

Did I make this up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can click the hatchery on the *minimap* instead of the main area. Some people swear by that method (for reasons you mentioned), others assert that it's still faster to just find an efficient way of doing it by clicking directly on the hatcheries. There's a tutorial from PsyStarcraft about doing it efficiently:

http://www.youtube.com/user/PsyStarcraft#p/search/4/gc-GwhjSn-k

I am not a Zerg player so I have no opinions on this.

Comment: yea, you select your queens, press 'v', hold shift and click at big green squares on map. You don't need to be precise - if you miss hatchery nothing will happened.

Answer (score 10):

There's also the [backspace method](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=125725) to inject. It works like this:

- You have all your Queens in one control-group (for example **4**)
- Activate the control group by pressing <kbd>4</kbd>
- Press <kbd>V</kbd> (for inject)
- Now press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, your view will center on a hatch.
- Hold shift while you click the hatch, followed by Backspace until you cycled through all your hatches.

After some practice, you can do this *really* fast. It's probably the fastest method to do multiple injects. Although you are actually moving your camera to every hatchery, you can do this so fast that you're back in battle almost instantly.

There's a drawback though: It works best if all your queens/hatches are ready for injection at the same time. It also doesn't work that well, if you have a hatch without a queen somewhere.

Comment: While a super-fast method of doing so (and the one I'd suggest that users employ since the mini-map can be imprecise in the heat of battle), it doesn't technically answer the question that was asked. The OP was looking for a method that did not require you going back to the hatchery and clicking on it.

Comment: @Shaun Yes I know, but I thought I throw this in, since there's also another answer that talks about centering on your hatch/queen. The latest trend of creating huge maps is also not in favor of the minimap method, where a hatchery suddenly becomes really small and therefore hard to click.

Comment: You can even re-map "Base camera" from `Backspace` to some more convenient key, like `Space`.

Comment: @sth: Good point. Never even thought of that.

Answer (score 3):

You did not imagine it, you can spawn larva by having the queens on a hotkey, make queens your active unit, press the spawn larva button (V), and then click on the hatchery/lair/hive on your mini-map. **The closest queen will move to that hatchery to spawn larva**.

This method though requires clicking on your minimap very accurately, if you don't then you're stuck with the targeting cross-hair for the larva inject spell.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple hatcheries in an area then tenfour's method won't be very effective. You can however double tap on your queen hotkey to centre the map on her, do your larvae business, and then double tap on your army hotkey to get back into the action.

However for expansions, the mini-map method works fine.